# How to perform SQL update using 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update data in 3 tables but I do not know how to use update statement in combination of select+join. Please let me know if there is something wrong. I am in phase of educating. Thanks

Here is the ER Diagram http://cramster-image.s3.amazonaws.com/definitions/9780071787536-f0281-01.jpg   and I want to update lets say some information about the client(customer)

```
 update client
    set 
    client.id_client = 100, client.name = 'Puma', address.street = 'Oxford Street',
    address.city = 'London', country.name = 'England'
    where client.id_client=1
    (select client.id_client,client.name, address.street, address.city, country.name
    from client
    join address on client.address.id_address=address.id_address
    join country on address.country_id_country= country_id_country);
```

Comment: First learn basics. That is completely incorrect statement.

Comment: What database and version is this for?

Comment: Something is wrong... I can't even figure out what you're trying to do. Add sample table data before and after the update. Also tag dbms used, the answer may be product specific.

Comment: @  Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister Oracle11.2

Comment: @jarlh Here is the ER Diagram http://cramster-image.s3.amazonaws.com/definitions/9780071787536-f0281-01.jpg   and I want to update lets say some information about the client(customer)

Comment: Your ER diagram doesn't match your query - it doesn't show address or country tables, and column names are different. Are you really trying to update three tables, or are you trying to update the client table with data from the other two (e.g. setting client.country_id to the ID value from the country table that matches the name England)?

Comment: Yes it isnt the same ER diagram, it was just for ilustration what is it about.

Comment: @alex poole http://prnt.sc/b1cc88 Here is model from SQL Developer. The red rectangle shows tables to change. For example i want to update information of client (where klient_id_klienta = 1). It means i update data in table Klient, Oblast, Adresa. This isnt in EN language but klient=client, oblast=country, adresa=address.

Answer (score 1):

For Mysql should be this

```
update client
   join address on ( client.address.id_address=address.id_address and client.id_client = 1 )
   join country on address.country_id_country= country_id_country  
set 
client.id_client = 100, 
client.name = 'Puma', 
address.street = 'Oxford Street',
address.city = 'London', 
country.name = 'England'
```

For Oracle you should use a stored procedure and perform separated update for single table.

Comment: If I use this I get 00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: Weel for oracle is not possible update multiple table with one query .. you must use store procedure .. i have update the answer .